# FreeRADIUS issue - (0) No reply from server for ID 176 socket 3

Tags: freeradius, radius

Command radtest test testing1234294106 127.0.0.1 18120 testing123

below is the output getting

```
Sent Access-Request Id 176 from 0.0.0.0:56553 to 127.0.0.1:1812 length 90
User-Name = "test"
User-Password = "testing1234294106"
NAS-IP-Address = 127.0.1.1
NAS-Port = 18120
Message-Authenticator = 0x00
Cleartext-Password = "testing1234294106"
Sent Access-Request Id 176 from 0.0.0.0:56553 to 127.0.0.1:1812 length 90
User-Name = "test"
User-Password = "testing1234294106"
NAS-IP-Address = 127.0.1.1
NAS-Port = 18120
Message-Authenticator = 0x00
Cleartext-Password = "testing1234294106"
Sent Access-Request Id 176 from 0.0.0.0:56553 to 127.0.0.1:1812 length 90
User-Name = "test"
User-Password = "testing1234294106"
NAS-IP-Address = 127.0.1.1
NAS-Port = 18120
Message-Authenticator = 0x00
Cleartext-Password = "testing1234294106"
(0) No reply from server for ID 176 socket 3
```

Comment: You need to run the server in debug mode, there's no way to tell what's happening just looking at the output of radtest. Use `radiusd -X` for the server to see what it's doing.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error coz I had not started the server.
use:

`sudo radiusd -X`

or:

`sudo /usr/sbin/freeradius radiusd -X`

Answer (score 0):

No reply, is frustrating. So here are general steps to diagnose a No reply situation. At the end of this post, I point out the solution to the OP's original question.

### Diagnosis Steps

If you get "No reply" from radtest, the first step is check the output of radiusd (which you need to have running in debug mode with cmd radiusd -X).

This will help you diagnose whether the request is being ignored or if the request isn't even making it to radiusd.

**Radiusd Ignoring Request**

In radiusd, if you see a message telling you that the request was "Ignored", read the reason for it being ignored and resolve the problem.

**Radiusd With No Output**

Alternatively, if radiusd -X doesn't show any output after attempting to connect, then most likely your request isn't even making it to the radiusd listener. This could happen if you're specifying an invalid ip address or port, or if a firewall is blocking the request, or if there's a routing problem.

*NOTE: I noticed that some default configurations run the radius server auth port on 18120 instead of 1812. Double check the listener port number by checking the output of radiusd -X.  The very end of the output should say "Listening for connections on..." followed by the IP Address and Port.*

### Solution to OP's problem

The Op's radtest command is incorrectly formatted. It says

```
radtest test testing1234294106 127.0.0.1 18120 testing123
```

The correct format is:

```
radtest test testing1234294106 127.0.0.1:18120 0 testing123
```

You can check this by running 'radtest --help'.  The format for the ip port portion is "ip:port nas-port".  In this case the nas-port can be 0.

You can also see, that since the port wasn't specified, the resulting request goes out on the default port 1812 (when it should have been 18120):

```
Sent Access-Request Id 176 from 0.0.0.0:56553 to 127.0.0.1:1812
```

I don't know why the out-of-box configuration for freeRadius uses 18120 for testing. But I think this throws a lot of people off. Especially since radtest syntax normally reads: ip:18120 0  (note the separated 0s).